# What is the alternative of SSLParameter.setServerNames in android sdk level 23

Tags: android, ssl, sni

I am using SSLSocket to connect to a server. I want to use ssl SNI extension. I can use `SSLParameter.setServerNames` in java. But it appears  in android it is not available till sdk 24. What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved by using reflection.
Connect the socket using:

```
SSLSocketFactory sf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(uri.getHost(), 443);
setSNIHost(sf, socket, uri.getHost());
SSLSession s = socket.getSession();
```

where setSNIHost is declared as:

```
public void setSNIHost(final SSLSocketFactory factory, final SSLSocket socket, final String hostname) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting SNI via SSLParameters");
        SNIHostName sniHostName = new SNIHostName(hostname);
        SSLParameters sslParameters = socket.getSSLParameters();
        List<SNIServerName> sniHostNameList = new ArrayList<>(1);
        sniHostNameList.add(sniHostName);
        sslParameters.setServerNames(sniHostNameList);
        socket.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
    } else if (factory instanceof android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting SNI via SSLCertificateSocketFactory");
        ((android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory)factory).setHostname(socket, hostname);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting SNI via reflection");
        try {
            socket.getClass().getMethod("setHostname", String.class).invoke(socket, hostname);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not call SSLSocket#setHostname(String) method ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really remember where I copied the code for the reflection, I simply added the support for API 24.